# Two increasing functions starting from same points and having identical limits coincide

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $f,g$ be two differentiable functions satisfying $f(0)=g(0)$, $f^\prime (x)\leq g^\prime (x)$ on $[0,\infty)$, and $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}f(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}g(x)=a\geq 0$.
I need to prove $f\equiv g$ over $[0,\infty)$.

I'm pretty sure this should be a simple application of the mean value theorem but I just don't see what to do. I managed to prove $f\leq g$ on $[0,\infty)$, but that didn't make use of the fact they have the same limits at infinity..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $h(x) = f(x) - g(x)$. Then, $h'(x) \le 0$, so $h \downarrow$. Moreover, $h(0) = 0$, and $\lim_{x \to \infty} h(x) = 0$. What can be concluded?

Comment: Got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that there is a point $x_0$ where the functions do not coincide, i.e. $f(x_0)= g(x_0)-c$ for some $c>0$. Then can you compare the two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)-c$ for $x\geq x_0$? What does $g(x)-c$ converge to as $x\to \infty$?

Comment: I think that by the same argument we'd have to have $f(x)\leq g(x)-c$. $g(x)$ would converge to $a-c$.

Comment: I hope you mean "$g(x)-c$ would converge to $a-c$". Anyways, yes, that's it. If $f(x)\leq g(x)-c$, could $f(x)$ still converge to $a$?

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks!